# Scala how to define objectFile[Type](path)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to read HDFS data, but the data may be saved as `saveAsObject[(String,Int,SparseVector)]` or `saveAsObject[(Int,String,Int)]` etc.

So I want to pass command line parameters like `"String,Int,SparseVector"` etc to my job via `spark-submit`.

How to get `enter code here`the `type` from the command line arguments for the method `saveAsObject[type]` ?

```
object Test2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val conf=new org.apache.spark.SparkConf()
  val sc = new org.apache.spark.SparkContext(conf)
  var fmt = "Int,String,SparseVector"
  if(args.size!=0){fmt=args(0)}
  var fmt_arr=fmt.split(",")
  type data_type=(matchClass(fmt_arr(0)),matchClass(fmt_arr(1)),matchClass(fmt_arr(2)))
  val data = sc.objectFile[data_type]("")
}

def matchClass(str:String)={
  str match {
  case "String" =>  String
  case "Int"    =>  Int
  case "SparseVector" => SparseVector
  case _ => throw new RuntimeException("unsupported type")
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Try to reformat your question and add some code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

All the configuration entries, you could have them in a so called application.conf file!

https://github.com/lightbend/config

You could then read this config file when you do the Spark submit! Have a look here for some examples on how to load an application.conf file into your application. The mechanism should be the same for a Spark application as well!

https://github.com/joesan/plant-simulator/blob/master/app/com/inland24/plantsim/config/AppConfig.scala